# Arduino + GSM shield V2 // How to use buzzer signal

Tags: arduino, gsm

I have a GSM shield V2 for Arduino, and I want some buzzer to make some noise when there is an incoming call. At this link http://www.thaieasyelec.net/archives/Manual/M10_HD_V1.00.pdf page 44 I found that by connecting a simple transistor and a buzzer to the actual "buzzer" pin I should be able to produce sound. I tried and that does not work as expected, all I get is noise from the GND of the shield, that typical GSM noise that everyone know of.

I also tried to connect another arduino as to analog read the buzzer signal, but I get nothing that look like a ringing tone.

Has anyone any idea? Did I forget to setup some things software wise? So far it seems that the buzzer behaviour is completely unrelated to anything code wise, there is just that "buzzer" pin, and that's it, nothing more to set up.

Any help would be much appreciated !
Cheers

Comment: Can you share the schematic? And also your buzzer details? Buzzer needs some frequency to produce that sound....some buzzers have that inbuilt while some don't, in which case you have to modify the code to produce that frequency. Simply switching on with transistor won't work.

Comment: @Mayank  I was a bit confused by your phrasing.  I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great beeper/alarm part I've used in a couple of recent projects.  It is loud but can be muffled.  It's self-driving, so all you have to do it supply it enough current at its rated voltage, like through a transistor or Darlington.  It has a wide voltage range, and runs great from 3.3V up to 20, So it's ideal for microcontroller projects at 3.3V or 5V.  No need to fiddle with timers or PWM to make it beep.  [Try out this great part.](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/pui-audio-inc/AI-3135-TF-LW100-R/668-1350-ND/1745459).  Drive it from any output pin to a small-signal transistor with a beta of 50 or better and you'll be good to go.  Turn output pin on, it starts.  Turn output pin off, it stops.  I made mine "chirp" like the alarm on a car security system.  Easiest thing in the world.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer ! In the meantime I thought I might was well drive a buzzer signal directly from my Arduino since I can detect when someone is calling. I also tried to plot the buzzer signal using serial plotter but I didn't get anything looking like a "on/off" audio signal, that buzzer is definitely elusive ... thanks for the beeper/alarm proposal :)

Comment: @ThomasPujolle  Quite welcome!  Upvote and/or Accept my answer so others might find it and help them too! :)